# handlemessage() function cannot delete message what it received

Tags: omnet++

i am trying to simulate my project in omnet++ 5.2.1 and try to dispose the cQueue and MACPacket (a custom message packet). But initially it creates a problem as
"undisposed object: (MACPacket) Aloha.node.DATA -- check module destructor"

But when i add a constructor and destructor into the code it exits with code: -1073740940

i really need your help.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The exit code `-1073740940` converted into hex is equal to:

> 0xC0000374

In Windows this error indicates a heap corruption.

---

To determine what part of code generates this exception, you may set in `omnetpp.ini`:

> debug-on-error = true

Then build the project in debug mode, and debug it. Debugger will stop just before the line which occurs an error. 
Reference: [OMNeT++ Debugging Tips](https://www.omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.CplusplusDebuggingTips)

Comment: i debug the code and got the following response. But i can not understand. The response is in link. please help. [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/2fgaf5hmq5a9c4j/Untitled.jpg) and               
[link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/kcvzb0gkkbz6ukf/Untitled1.jpg). If you interested i can send you my code too.

Comment: You are probably deleting elements in your destructor that aren't really there anymore. Undisposed objects appear (for example) when you duplicate packets without disposing the copy/original. Encapsulation and decapsulation will also lead to packet duplications and thus undisposed objects when you don't take care of them properly.
Best advise is to ignore the undisposed objects if you are not too familiar with programming for OMNeT++. It is a warning, not an error which can often be ignored for short tests/simulations.

Comment: yes. i ignored it in previous for short simulations but now i want to run a large simulation that consumes a lot of time in case of undisposed packet object. my updated code link is here [link]  (http://www.mediafire.com/file/lffcfkff8410z80/alohaNFC-27-2-18.zip) please help.

Comment: You do not remove messages that are received in `hadleMessage()` of `Wsink` and `Wnode`. I suggest you editing your question and adding the content of `hadleMessage()` from the above mentioned files.

Comment: The code is posted is the link [link](http://www.mediafire.com/file/lffcfkff8410z80/alohaNFC-27-2-18.zip)

Comment: According to SO rules: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - **but also include the code in your question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) When the link to your code will be inactive, the answers will be useless. So I suggest inserting the content of `hadleMessage()` of your simple modules into your question.